# C# how to pass a DataTable parameter without a UDT to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I am trying to dynamically bulk merge data into a database from an API.

I have written code that is using reflection to create `DataTable` variables in C# and I am generating some SQL to do the merge in SQL Server and pass the `DataTable` variable with the SQL to execute.

But when I try and pass the `DataTable` as a parameter it need a `TypeName` for a User Defined Table Type `UDT` on the server.

I want to avoid having to setup a `UDT` on the server because I don't have the permission to do this and because the data is changing regularly so I want to be able to create the table dynamically and I would like to be able to pass the data type information in from C#.

Is there a way I can pass the `UDT` data type information in with the `DataTable` type, or a different way to pass the table to the database with the SQL command?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can pass the UDT data type information in with the DataTable type, or a different way to pass the table to the database with the SQL command?

You can only use table-valued parameters in conjunction with a user-defined table type.

The other main alternative to moving data into a database en-masse is with `BULK COPY` - this predates table-valued parameters. ADO.NET [supports BULK COPY directly with `SqlBulkCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8).

Note that `SqlBulkCopy` is intended for inserting directly into a table - I don't believe it can be used to execute a sproc directly, but you can use `SqlBulkCopy` to insert into a temporary-table and then reference that temporary-table in a sproc if you so wish.

[This blog article has other suggestions and examples too](https://richorama.github.io/2017/11/28/sql-bulk-copy/).